# How to get JBehave to include test dependency jars when running in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, bdd, jbehave

I've got a simple-enough project that I'm trying to test with JBehave core, and doing things in a maven-kosher fashion (that is production under src/main, test under src/test, integration testing stuff under an added path of src/it/{java,resources}, and test dependencies scoped with test). Getting this all running together seems rather harder than it should be.

My case is a little different because my code is in src/it/java, and resources in src/it/resources. Having configured those in maven, Eclipse runs the stories just fine - the problem is with Maven.

Currently my problem is that it doesn't see mockito (or other test dependencies) when running (mvn -X). Even editing a working example and adding a test dependency doesn't include it.

I've been able to bodge it into working by sticking my test dependencies within the plugin xml blob, but obviously I don't want to repeat myself like that.

The relevant parts of the build file (without the manually specified dependency hack) are:

```
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </testResource>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

...

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>embeddable-stories</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Story.java</include>
          </includes>
          <ignoreFailureInStories>false</ignoreFailureInStories>
          <ignoreFailureInView>false</ignoreFailureInView>
          <scope>test</scope>
          <testSourceDirectory>src/it/java</testSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The plugin has property `scope` which defaults to `compile`, I suppose you should to change it to `test`. Consult with the [documentation](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/maven-goals.html).

Also, [here is good point](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/examples-philosophy.html) why `compile` is by default.

Comment: I like the point about keeping it in src/main. I tried `<scope>test</scope>` but Maven still seemed to ignore it. Does that `<scope>` element belong in the `<dependency>` element? It doesn't seem to make Maven make jBehave look in the right place.

Comment: @MichaelOsofsky This `<scope>` is a part of plugin configuration too.

Comment: Thanks @kan, it looks like `<scope>` belongs in the `<configuration>` element of `<plugin>`.  Thank you!

Comment: I ran into one issue with keeping JBehave in src/main instead of src/test.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629791/adding-runwith-for-jbehave-junit-runner-breaks-jbehave-build-using-maven/27629792#27629792

Answer (score 2):

According to jbehave maven plugin [documentation](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/maven-goals.html),

> When using the JBehave Maven Plugin,
>   and depending on the rest of your POM
>   configuration, you may need to add
>   Apache log4j as Plugin Dependency (as
>   opposed to the Project Dependency) if
>   you find that it's not able to load
>   its classes

Could you be facing the same issue?

Comment: Well, this is what I meant when I said "sticking my test dependencies within the plugin xml blob", but I don't think it's a good solution - from the looks of it, I need to duplicate all my test dependencies in there. Perhaps I'll ask on the mailing list and report any findings back here.

Comment: @Dave LeBlanc. According to the doc, *only* log4j was required.  I guess it is more than that in your case

Comment: @DaveLeBlanc did you get an answer?