# Adding @RunWith for jbehave-junit-runner breaks JBehave build using Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, bdd, jbehave

I'm using JBehave with my Maven build which I also develop in Eclipse and sometimes run the my unit tests with the JUnit runner in Eclipse.  I found jbehave-junit-runner works well for beautifying the JBehave stories in the JUnit runner.  However, adding jbehave-junit-runner seems to have broken my Maven build.

Result of `mvn clean install` after installing https://github.com/codecentric/jbehave-junit-runner:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/src/main/java/com/netbase/followerdownloader/FollowerDownloaderStories.java:[28,23] error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/src/main/java/com/netbase/followerdownloader/FollowerDownloaderStories.java:[42,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class RunWith
/Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/src/main/java/com/netbase/followerdownloader/FollowerDownloaderStories.java:[28,23] error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/src/main/java/com/netbase/followerdownloader/FollowerDownloaderStories.java:[42,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class RunWith
/Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/src/main/java/com/netbase/followerdownloader/FollowerDownloaderStories.java:[50,28] error: cannot access Runner
[INFO] 5 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.043 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-23T15:38:39-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/156M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project followerdownloader-frontend: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/src/main/java/com/netbase/followerdownloader/FollowerDownloaderStories.java:[28,23] error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/src/main/java/com/netbase/followerdownloader/FollowerDownloaderStories.java:[42,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/src/main/java/com/netbase/followerdownloader/FollowerDownloaderStories.java:[28,23] error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/src/main/java/com/netbase/followerdownloader/FollowerDownloaderStories.java:[42,1] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class RunWith
[ERROR] /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/src/main/java/com/netbase/followerdownloader/FollowerDownloaderStories.java:[50,28] error: cannot access Runner
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

What is it about https://github.com/codecentric/jbehave-junit-runner that broke my build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to broaden the scope of junit by removing the test element from the junit  in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->     <!-- SOLUTION: COMMENTED OUT THIS LINE -->
</dependency>
```

I think I stumbled into a paradox of JBehave and Behavior Driven Design (BDD):

- On the one hand, BDD is not testing (see http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/examples-philosophy.html).
- On the other hand, a tool for BDD, https://github.com/codecentric/jbehave-junit-runner, depends on the @RunWith annotation that's in a test framework, specifically org.junit.runner.RunWith.

I worry that my solution may have consequences for my production code if I'm no longer limiting the scope of junit to the [Maven standard test directory](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Nevertheless, my solution did solve the original problem.

Comment: JBehave is talking about creating an own module for the behaviours. Make junit only compile scope in that module, then JUnit will not be part of your production code unless your behaviours are not part of your production code.

Comment: Thank you @StefanBirkner. I have a lot to sort out since I'm trying to make this work on Google App Engine which has its own requirements for modules (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/). A related issue is how to share code across all these modules (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388111/can-google-app-engine-modules-share-source-code-just-like-maven-modules). I'm sure there aren't easy answers to these issues, but if you have more insights, I'd welcome them.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have more insights.